# How to mark folders or files so that macOS Sierra doesn't copy to iCloud

Tags: macos, icloud

I recently installed macOS Sierra and accepted the default option to store documents to iCloud.  It seemed like a nice convenience; however, I very quickly realized that it does not work well for users like me who have very large files or apps that create very large files.

When I restored my documents and other project files, within minutes macOS's iCloud service consumed all of the allotted free space and I've an annoying "Upgrade..." item in Finder now.

It's a nice feature, and perhaps will prove convenient for "normal" files, but as things are it's worthless and actually very inconvenient because of the large every day work files that I create consumed all space.  It would be ideal to flag those large files somehow and not allow them to consume all the allotted free iCloud space.   I've no intention of ever paying a subscription.

Is there a way to manage or flag folders and files to NOT be duplicated to iCloud (besides just moving them out of the typical user profile folders)?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently if you have selected `Documents`, it will sync all the files from it. I'd suggest excluding the `Documents` and select individual folder which you want to backup.

Comment: I guess I'm overlooking the obvious.  Where can I exclude Documents and the select individual folders?  I found in iCloud settings that I could uncheck the "Desktop & Documents Folders", but that is too aggressive without being able to select specific folders as you suggested.

Comment: I meant something like this. http://www.imore.com/how-manually-create-folders-and-move-files-icloud-drive. See backup is something Time Capsule take cares.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the extension .nosync to specific files and folders, or a folder titled tmp.